# swal.queue() function removed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sweetalert2

I was using sweetalert2 version 10+ and using the queue() function. This was removed in version 11+ which I'm trying to upgrade to. I understand the reasoning for using promises instead, but in my use case this does not apply.... Here's the scenario that works perfectly in version 10:

I am showing a swal modal waiting for the user to respond. During the modal being still visible, a push notification arrives, which is automatically handled by the app (since it's in the foreground), and this notification needs a swal to be shown. I don't want to interrupt what the user is doing, so I "queue" the new swal, until the user is done with the one already on his screen, and *then* I show the swal generated by the push notification.

If the queue() function is removed, could somebody give me any hints as to how to accomplish the above without it?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

here is an example from sweetalert2 official for sweetalert2 version 11+. hope it helpful.
[queue-with-progress-steps](https://sweetalert2.github.io/recipe-gallery/queue-with-progress-steps.html)

the following is the example enhanced based on above example for your reference.

```js
async function login() {
    const steps = ["1", "2", "3"];
    const Queue = Swal.mixin({
        progressSteps: steps,
        confirmButtonText: "Next >",
        // optional classes to avoid backdrop blinking between steps
        showClass: { backdrop: "swal2-noanimation" },
        hideClass: { backdrop: "swal2-noanimation" },
    });
    const userName = await Queue.fire({
        title: "User name",
        input: "text",
        currentProgressStep: 0,
        inputPlaceholder: "Please Input userName",
        html: "some tips",
    });
    const password = await Queue.fire({
        title: "password",
        input: "password",
        currentProgressStep: 1,
        inputPlaceholder: "please input password",
         html: "some tips",
    });
    const validationCode = await Queue.fire({
        title: "validation code",
        input: "text",
        currentProgressStep: 2,
        inputPlaceholder: "please input validation code",
         html: "<a>click to refresh validation code</a>",
        confirmButtonText: "OK",
        showClass: { backdrop: "swal2-noanimation" },
    });

    Swal.fire({
        title: "All done!",
        html: `
        Your inputs:
        <pre><code>${validationCode.value}:${password.value} :${userName.value}</code></pre>
        `,
        confirmButtonText: "login!",
    });
}
```